# Excessive amount of queries on ServerFault Blog?

Tags: discussion

I was scrolling through the blog for ServerFault and at the bottom I noticed this:

[image]

Is 38 queries normal for a blog homepage? I would have thought about 10 max?

Don't get me wrong the load time is fine, just seemed a bit curious to me.

Comment: it's wordpress ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Server Fault blog uses WordPress.

The number of database queries WordPress uses to render any given page varies widely, but 38 is very close to the low end. It doesn't appear to be a cause for concern.

Further reading:

- [Help with WP_Query - Too many mySQL queries](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70794/18054)
- [How many Queries are too many?](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/07/12/how-many-queries-are-too-many/)

Comment: That makes alot more sense. Ta.